# javafx - drag to filesystem - get path

Tags: javafx

I am relatively new to java and javafx. So my program is a product of my growing java skills:) and "thankfully" copying stuff from the growing quantity of javafx howto's.

Well now i am stuck on a problem and I have spent now quite a time looking for the solution before asking you guys. Basically I have builtin this application a very simple ftp-client using the apache common library, which does a connection and loads the ftpfiles into a tablerow and one can browse through the directories, what for I have implemented some FTPCLient functionalities on a seperate class. Well I already have set up a dragin-files functionality from the os's filesystem into the tableview, which does the upload of files part very well.

*But know I would like to be implement the drag/copy file from the tableview to the filesystem. I am very thankful if anyone could give me a short description on how to do that. I think I could get that done, if I could get the path of the target-directory when dragging to it. Probably set up in a row- or cellfactory.*

Thanks in advance guys,